# How to find/export only one value (primary SMTP) from multi-valued Proxy Addresses

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I have a script which search values in attribute Company and Proxy Addresses.

`Get-ADUser  -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Stu,OU=LOWA,OU=IDLOWA,DC=ad,DC=ju,DC=com' -Properties company,proxyaddresses | select company, @{L='ProxyAddress'; E={$_.proxyaddresses -join"; "}}`

Company has two char, but Proxy Addresses is multi-valued, for example:

`smtp:adam@ff.ju.com,SMTP:adam@zf.ju.com,smtp:adam@ju.com`

or

`smtp:adam@ff.ju.com,SMTP:adam@ef.ju.com`

or

`SMTP:adam@ff.ju.com`

I need export/save to variable or csv file only primary SMTP address, that means `SMTP:xxx@xxx`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code will get you all the primary SMTP addresses for the given searchbase parameter, pipes the output to a TXT file. Maybe it needs a little tweaking for some more info, but I think this will get you going:

```
$users = Get-ADUser  -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Stu,OU=LOWA,OU=IDLOWA,DC=ad,DC=ju,DC=com' -Properties proxyaddresses
$primarySMTPAddress = @()
foreach ($address in $users.proxyAddresses)
{
    if (($address.Length -gt 5) -and ($address.SubString(0,5) -ceq 'SMTP:'))
    {
        $primarySMTPAddress += $address.SubString(5)
    }
}

$primarySMTPAddress | out-file -Pathg C:\tmp\PrimarySMTPAdresses.txt
```

Change the out-file path to a valid location.